# "NDK not configured." in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, android-ndk

I'm trying to get the Moor library working for Flutter, but I'm getting this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':moor_ffi'.
> NDK not configured. 
  Download it with SDK manager.
```

The example [here](https://github.com/rodydavis/moor_shared) is what I'm trying to run.

I've downloaded the NDK in the Android Studio SDK manager.

Answer (score 2):

For windows,
You'll have to set the path to the NDK or CMAKE:

In the file local.properties add:

```
cmake.dir=C:\\Users\\to\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\cmake\\3.10.2.4988404
ndk.dir=C:\\Users\\to\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set the path to the NDK:

For example:
In your project/android folder:

In the file `local.properties` add:

`ndk.dir=/Users/his/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669`